# getting numbers from a string with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am working in a project which it needs to get a phone number from a string. the string is like this in Java Script array named dine

```
{
"group": 1, 

"tel1": "Tél(1): 05.82.77.31.78", 
"tel2": "Tél(2): 09.55.86.31.45", 

}, 
,...
```

I want to use pure phone numbers in a tag like this

```
<a href="tel:0970500469">Tél: 09.70.50.04.69</a>
```

I have used this java script codes

```
for (var i = 0; i < dine.length; i++) {
  telnom = dine[i].tel1;
  telnom = telnom.replace(/\D/g, '');

  alert(telnom);

  telnom2 = dine[i].tel2;
  telnom2 = telnom2.replace(/\D/g, '');
  alert(telnom2);

  infoHtml += '<div class="info">\n <p> <a href="tel:' + telnom + '">' + dine[i].tel1 + '</a></p>\n    <p> <a href="tel:' + telnom2 + '">' + dine[i].tel2 + '</a></p>\n  \n</div>';
}
```

the problem is that it added 1 at the beginning of my phone number that it seems belongs to the `Tél(1)` and makes the telnom1 like this : `10970500469` while I want to call `0970500469`

I am sure the problem stand for the way I used replace codes but I really do not know how to correct it.

```
 telnom = dine[i].tel1;

 telnom = telnom.replace(/\D/g, '');

 telnom2 = dine[i].tel2;

 telnom2 = telnom2.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

I really appreciate any help. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove any digits that appear within brackets, as well as non digits. Your regext should be `/(\(\d*\)|\D)/g`

```js
var telnom = "Tel:(1) - 05.34.36.15"

telnom = telnom.replace(/(\(\d*\)|\D)/g, '');

console.log(telnom);   //05343615
```

Comment: it seems it works fine. thank you . may I ask you a brief explanation ?  you remove every characters plus anything in bracket right? good job thank you

Comment: Yes exactly. @nedaDerakhshesh

Answer (score 1):

If your phone numbers always start with something like `Tel:`, `Tel(1):` etc you could, for example, consider simply splitting the whole string first using `:` (or a space) as separators. Like this:

```
telnom = dine[i].tel1;
telnom = telnom.split(":")[1].replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to get the desired telephone number:

```js
var n = "Tél(1): 05.82.77.31.78".match(/[\d]\d+/g).join("");
console.log(n);
```

Explanation: `[\d]` matches only numbers and we are adding another \d so only two numbers which are side-by-side matches. Next, we join them to a single string. If you need number instead of the string you can do following:
`Number(n)`